# Configuring NGINX on a flask web app in a Windows machine with Gunicorn

Tags: nginx, heroku, flask, window, gunicorn

I have a web app written in Python flask and deployed to Heroku.
It is also using Gunicorn.
The main feature of this app is to serve static images.
Gunicorn works fine with a low load of users but I want it to scale good in case my app will be used by thousands of people,
I was advised to configure NGINX which will serve the static images better and will also cache them.
The problem is that I am using a windows machine and all guides for doing this are for UNIX (mostly Ubunto)

Did any one find a guide to how to confiure NGINX with flask and guincorn on a Windows machine to an app deployed on Heroku?